# Power Bi subscriptions

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I want to run power bi subscription in power shell command. I am new to that subscription concept. Can anyone give the clear explanation about this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of "subscription"? E-mail subscription, so you want to trigger sending of the report to users, who subscribed to it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically trigger [e-mail subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe). They are running according their schedule. But you can use [Export to File API](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-report-to-pdf-pptx-and-png-files-using-power-bi-rest-api/) to export the report to a PDF file (or some other [supported file type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to)) and send it to someone. This means that the workspace must be attached to a dedicated capacity ([Power BI Premium P SKU, Power BI Premium EM SKU](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) or [Power BI Embedded A SKU](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/), and probably [Premium per user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-per-user-faq)) and you should maintain the list of "subscribers" on your own.

Here is some PowerShell code, which uses [Power BI Management CmdLets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps), which will export a report to PDF and send it by e-mail. You need to edit the parameters in the beginning of the code, like report ID, workspace ID, credentials, recipients, etc.

```
#############################################################
# Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
# Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -Scope CurrentUser
#############################################################
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

#############################################################
# Power BI settings
#############################################################
$password = "SuperStrongPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "account@example.com" 

#############################################################
# Report settings
#############################################################
$groupId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$reportId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$format = "PDF" # or PNG, or PPTX. For paginated reports can be CSV, DOCX, IMAGE (i.e. page definition plus file format - BMP, EMF, etc.), MHTML, XLSX or XML
$saveToFolder = "D:\"
$fileSuffix = " (" + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ")"


#############################################################
# E-mail settings
#############################################################
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = 587
$emailTo = $username
$emailSubject = "Here is your report"
$emailBodyHtml = "Please find <b>your report</b> attached here."
$emailUser = "account@example.com"
$emailPassword = "SuperStrongPassword"
$emailFrom = $emailUser


$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential



$settings = @{ includeHiddenPages = $false; locale = "en-us" }
$powerBIReportConfiguration = @{ settings = $settings }
$export_body = @{ format = $format; powerBIReportConfiguration = $powerBIReportConfiguration }
#'{
#  format: "$format",
#  powerBIReportConfiguration: { settings: { includeHiddenPages: false, locale: "en-us" } }
#}'

$export_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$groupId/reports/$reportId/ExportTo" -Method Post -Body ($export_body | ConvertTo-Json)

$export_response_json = ConvertFrom-Json $export_response

$exportId = $export_response_json.id

Write-Output "Polling export status..."
$maxPollCount = 500
$exportSucceeded = $false
do
{
    $maxPollCount = $maxPollCount - 1

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    $status_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$groupId/reports/$reportId/exports/$exportId" -Method Get

    $status_response_json = ConvertFrom-Json $status_response
    $status = $status_response_json.status
    $percentComplete = $status_response_json.percentComplete

    Write-Output "Status: $status, percent complete: $percentComplete (retries left: $maxPollCount)"

    if ($status -eq "Succeeded")
    {
        $exportSucceeded = $true
        $resourceLocation = $status_response_json.resourceLocation
        $reportName = $status_response_json.reportName
        $resourceFileExtension = $status_response_json.resourceFileExtension
        $outFile = [IO.Path]::Combine($saveToFolder, $reportName + $fileSuffix + $resourceFileExtension)
    }
}
until($exportSucceeded -or $maxPollCount -le 0)


Write-Output "Downloading export..."
$download_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $resourceLocation -Method Get -OutFile $outFile
Write-Output "Download completed."


Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount


$emailCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $emailUser, $($emailPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom `
    -To $emailTo `
    -Subject $emailSubject `
    -Body $emailBodyHtml `
    -BodyAsHtml `
    -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer `
    -Credential $emailCredentials `
    -UseSsl `
    -Attachments $outFile
```